# Taking literals out of phone number using .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am trying to remove the literals in a phone number (999) 999-9999 to make it 9999999999 in another hidden input value.

Can this be accomplished using the .val() function or can you only add more values to the hidden input?

phone1= (999) 999-9999

phone should have this value= 9999999999

```
        $('#phone1').bind('keypress blur', function() {

    $('#phone').val($('#phone1').val() + ' ' );
    });
```

Comment: Try using a regular expression for extracting the numbers from the value.

Comment: Re: "literals" -- You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: `$('#phone').val($('#phone1').val().replace(/\D/g, ''));`?

Comment: i mean the parentheses, -, and spaces.  everything that isn't a number

Comment: thanks, used the .replace from apsillers, works perfect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. get value
2. run [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
3. set value

Basic idea with a plain string

```
var str = "(999) 999-9999 ";
var newStr = str.replace(/\D/g,"");
console.log(newStr);
```

Now the best way to write what you did would be

```
$('#phone1').on('blur', function() {  //jQuery 1.7.2+ use on, not bind
    var txtBox = $(this);
    txtBox.val( txtBox.val().replace(/\D/g,"") );
});
```

Comment: While this solution works, it would be much better to use a regular expression for extracting the numbers from the input. Besides he can also validate if a phone number is formatted already or if the user input the data without format.

Comment: @XtianMacedo I love the fact you add more requirements to it than what the user asked for. Thanks for the -1, guessing it was from you.

Comment: @XtianMacedo It has regex `/\D/g`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#phone1').on('keypress blur', function() {
    $('#phone').val(this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "") + ' ' );
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yYNFY/2/)

Comment: @epascarello - So what, are you saying one is better then the other ?

Comment: It means you are reinventing the wheel. `[^\d]` is the same thing as `\D`. It just requires 3 more characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `replace` *<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)</sup>* method. It's what's going to do most of the work for you:

```
$('#phone').val($('#phone1').val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

The first parameter can be either a substring or a regular expression. In the example, I've used the regex for "not a digit".

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the regex initially, but it's fixed now. Sorry for the confusion.